# Smart way to add elements to all objects in array? js/jquery/knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

for example I have an array like this:

```
var t = ko.observableArray([
  {"FoodName":"Rice","FoodOften":"2"},
  {"FoodName":"Apple","FoodOften":"3"}
]);
```

How can I add an static item to all of them like below in a smart way?

```
[
  {"Student":"1","FoodName":"Rice","FoodOften":"2"},    
  {"Student":"1","FoodName":"Apple","FoodOften":"3"}      
]
```

I know I can loop `t().length` to add `t()[n].Student="1"` but just wondering is there any smart way for knockout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every variation on answering this question is going to be some form of 'iterate over the array and add the value to each object'. A few:

```
t.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry.Student = 1;
});

var newT = t.map(function(entry) {
    entry.Student = 1;
    return entry;
});

for (var i = 0; i++; i< t.length) {
    t[i].Student = 1;
}
```

Incidentally, at least in Chrome, jsperf says the first is the most efficient of those three.